# Variável não assinada vs variável null

Tags: c#, variáveis, característica-linguagem

Eu tenho os seguintes códigos:

```
String str = null;
```

e

```
String str;
```

Se eu usar um `if` para verificar se as variáveis são `null`, o if será "chamado" nos dois casos. Porém tem alguma diferença entre os dois códigos? Creio que tenha uma pequena diferença, pois eu não posso usar uma variável local não assinada, mas posso usar uma variável local valendo `null`.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta marcada responde o que tem aqui.

Comment: vc está de clarando na class ou  no  method ?

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons na class